# Determining the camera's visible x,y of an object in the scene

Tags: javascript, canvas, 3d, three.js, frustum

I am trying to determine the location (x, y, z coordinates ) of an object (a BoxGeometry) in the world with respect to the screen (frustum) and not the world.  The frustum.intersectsObject(…) method simply returns a Boolean, I want to determine what quadrant ([-x,y],[x,y],[x,-y],[-x,-y]) a box is in relative to the camera (the red lines in the screenshot below follow the camera and not the scene) .  Right now, everything works as long as the camera is not rotated (`room.children[i].position.x`) because then the camera and the world have the same coordinates but the moment I rotate the camera, this does not work.

I think things are showing up in `if (frustum.intersectsObject(room.children[i])) {` that shouldn't be. (See image below)

I'm new to three.js, so there is probably an easy way to do this that I have not happened across.  If for some reason there is not, what would be the easiest way to implement such a thing?  Thanks!!

```
    function onDocumentKeyDown(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var frustum = new THREE.Frustum();
        frustum.setFromMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().multiply(camera.projectionMatrix));
        for (var i = 0; i < room.children.length; i++) {
            if (frustum.intersectsObject(room.children[i])) {
                var XYZ=new THREE.Vector4();
                XYZ.copy(room.children[i].position).applyMatrix4(camera.matrixWorldInverse);
                console.log(i, 'left', frustum.intersectsObject(room.children[i]), XYZ.x,XYZ.y,XYZ.z,XYZ.w, room.children[i].material.emissive.getHex());
                    if (XYZ.x < 0 && XYZ.y > 0 && (event.keyCode === 103 || event.keyCode === 13) ) {
                        if (room.children[i].material.emissive.getHex() !== 255) {
                            $('#score').text(score++);
                            room.children[i].material.emissive.setHex(0x00ff00);
                            console.log(frustum);
                            console.log(i, 'WHAT ARE THE BOUNDING BOX COORDINATES OF THIS BOX????');
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: Determining the location of an object in the world with respect to the screen (frustum) and not the world.]

Comment: Do you mean you want the camera-space coordinates of a world-space point?  `vector.copy( point ).applyMatrix4( camera.matrixWorldInverse );`

Comment: Basically what I want is to determine what quadrant ([-x,y],[x,y],[x,-y],[-x,-y]) the box is in relative to the camera (the red lines follow the camera and not the scene).

Answer (score 0):

The [Vector3.project( camera )](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Vector3.project) method seems to do what you are looking for. This will give you the position of an object in normalized device coordinates, which should range from -1 to 1 in both x and y directions.

```
vector.set( x, y, z ) // or vector.copy( ...)
vector.project( camera )
if ( vector.x <= 0 ) {
    ...
}
```

should be true if the object is in the left half of the view, though I haven't tested it.